# Audio Constructor in Javascript is returning NaN

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was trying to to get duration of audio files using creating audio Constructor in a for Each Loop but audioElement.duration is returning NaN only.
Here's my code.

```js
let audioArray = [
    '1.mp3',
    '2.mp3',
    '3.mp3',
    '4.mp3'
]

let audioElement;

audioArray.forEach((element)=>{
    audioElement = new Audio(element);
    console.log(audioElement.duration);
})
```

Comment: A string points to a path that does not have a duration.

Comment: It has to load.... You need to wait

Answer (score 1):

The browser won't know the duration until enough of the file has been downloaded, so you need to wait for the correct event.

See this snippet from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement

```
audioElement.addEventListener('loadeddata', () => {
  let duration = audioElement.duration;
  // The duration variable now holds the duration (in seconds) of the audio clip
})
```

In your example, to log out the durations you would do this:

```
let audioArray = [
    '1.mp3',
    '2.mp3',
    '3.mp3',
    '4.mp3'
]
audioArray.forEach((element)=>{
    let audioElement = new Audio(element);
    audioElement.addEventListener('loadeddata', () => {
      console.log(`${element} duration:`, audioElement.duration);
    });
});
```